# How to uninstall libraries (installed through compile) in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I tried installing libtiff 4.0.3 through using the commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

It installed fine. However, I recently found out that I got the versions wrong and so I need to install a new one with a different version. I'd like to how know to remove libtiff from my Ubuntu setup. Would it be the same as `sudo apt-get remove [x]`? And how do I know what to put on `x` if I didn't install it through `sudo apt-get install [x]` command? Would appreciate some help. Thanks. :)

Comment: You can't use `apt-get` to remove something that wasn't installed as a package. Try running `make uninstall`.

Comment: I see.. thanks. I didn't know that existed. :P thanks. You might want to put that as an answer so that I can check? I've always wondered how to do this. :D

Comment: Beware that some software don't know about `make uninstall` (e.g. GCC)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use apt-get to remove something that wasn't installed as a package. Try running make uninstall. –  [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778294/how-to-uninstall-libraries-installed-through-compile-in-ubuntu/24672733#24672733)